# Why is my inline CSS working but not the CSS in the head tag?

Tags: css

Why is it that this inline CSS works fine.

```
<a href="error.php" class="reportBug"
style="display:scroll ;position:fixed; bottom:210px; right:2px;"> 
    <img src="images/Report_Error.png" border="0">
</a>
```

But it doesn't work when I put the CSS in `<head>`.

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #reportBug {
      display:scroll;
      position:fixed;
      bottom:210px
      right:2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="error.php" class="reportBug"> 
    <img src="images/Report_Error.png" border="0">
  </a>
</body>
```

What is the difference between the two, and why doesn't the second way work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When assigning an element to a class you use `.` notation. IDs use `#`.

```
<style type="text/css">
 #reportBug {
   display:scroll;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:210px
   right:2px;
 }
</style>
```

Should be

```
<style type="text/css">
 .reportBug {
   display:scroll;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:210px
   right:2px;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference `reportBug` as a class like this:

```
.reportBug {
 display:scroll;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:210px
 right:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your stylesheet, you used `#reportBug`. That's for `id="reportBug"`, not `class="reportBug"`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides, I think you miss something in the declaration of the class `reportBug`, `bottom` needs the `;` at the end, otherwise, `right: 2px;` is going to be ignored.

```
 .reportBug {
   display:scroll;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:210px;
   right:2px;
 }
```